# adding bootstrap active class in navigation with codeigniter and Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

i wand to add bootstrap active class to my navigation. In navigation i used href

which is codeigniter link means will redirect to new page and active class will be added to it through angularjs. My navigation is

```
<ul>
<li ng-class="{active:isActive('/c_home')}"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>c_home>home</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active:isActive('/c_contact')}" ><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>c_contact>contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

while my js function without app and controller only using function

```
$scope.isActive = function(currentLocation){
```

return currentLocation === $location.path();

}

My problem is that active class apply after second click. I mean to say that on first click does not work.

I guess that angularjs function call before loading codeigniter url

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used CI with Angularjs, but when I want to put an active class to a link from my navbar, this is what I use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("part_of_uri") > -1) {
       $("#menu_item_a").removeClass('active');
       $("#menu_item_b").addClass('active');
    } else if (window.location.href.indexOf("another_part_of_uri") > -1) {
        $("#menu_item_b").removeClass('active');
        $("#menu_item_a").addClass('active');
    } ... // and goes on
});
```

What this does is that, if the string `part_of_uri` matches a fragment of your url, then removes active class from `menu_item_a` and applies it to `menu_item_b` and so on, with as many menu items you need.

Hope is of some help!